# Is there a way to run code when FCM Message is received, even when app is killed?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a cross platform app (only works on android for now) with Flutter, that notifies the user when a operation is ongoing (for volunteer firefighters) and they can send feedback if they will be participating. I did that with a FCM Notification and data payload. Now i am trying to implement a function, that will not show a notification and tell the server, that they do not have time. I am using flutter_local_notifications for the notification. When i am in the app or have the app minimzed, it works perfectly. But when "kill" the app when swiping up in the app drawer, I no longer get a notification.

I was expecting it to show, as it is a data only message (no notification field provided). The function should be implemented clientside, so it should not send a request to the server to stop sending the notifications. Is there any way to either run a seperate piece of code in the FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundNotification(function) or is it possible to prevent the user from killing the app? Is there a background service I can maybe implement? I searched hours but with no result. I hope there is a solution, that works on both platforms (iOS, Android)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle background messages when app is terminated via the `onBackgroundMessage` handler. Data only messages are considered low priority by devices when your application is in the background or terminated, and will be ignored. You can however explicitly increase the priority by sending additional properties on the FCM payload.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Comment: I am using the onBackgroundMessage handler. I also set @pragma("vm:entry-point") to avoid tree shaking issues. It does not work when i swipe up in app drawer. That is my problem. When it is just in the background, there is no problem.

Comment: I also set priority to high. So i have no idea why it isn't working. I am looking into whether the battery optimisation is a problem, as i have the suspicion, that android automatically kills apps when "killed" in app drawer.

Comment: I have also now experimented, and found out that it is not a problem with the plugin. I tried writing to a sqlite database, but when the app is terminated, that is also not working. I am really out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by disabling battery optimization and by adding the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission to my manifest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).